# Indentation after section title on a first item of "easylist" item

Tags: sectioning, xetex, indentation, sections-paragraphs

The code:

```
% XeLaTeX

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[50, sharp]{easylist}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Minion Pro:+onum}

\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}


\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\filcenter}{ARTICLE\ \thesection:\ }{0pt}{}

\begin{document}

% . . .

\section{SCOPE OF CONTRACT}
\begin{easylist}
\ListProperties(Start1*=\thesection, Mark={.}, FinalMark=, Hang=true, Margin=0in, Align=0.5in, Space=6pt, Space*=6pt)

## The scope of the present Contract is to lay down the terms and conditions under which the SUPPLIER agrees to sell and deliver to the PURCHASER, and the PURCHASER agrees to purchase from the SUPPLIER the Equipment and Documentation at the terms and conditions as specified in this Contract and its Annexes.

## The material list, attached as Annex 1, is an integral part of this Contract and is in accordance with the Technical Terms and Conditions. Notarized Copies of the respective certificates of compliance of the Ministry for Telecommunication and Information of the Russian Federation (Minsvjazi) for the Equipment supplied under this Contract shall be handed over by the SUPPLIER to the PURCHASER immediately after signature of this Contract. 
\end{easylist}

% . . .

\end{document}
```

Makes result:

[image]

How to avoid indentation at 2.1?

Comment: Add a `\noindent` just before the list.

Answer (score 4):

You can solve the issue by saying `\usepackage{indentfirst}`

Full example, with corrections for the package loading:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[50, sharp]{easylist}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{indentfirst} % <--- added

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Minion Pro:+onum}

\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Ligatures=TeX]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}


\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\filcenter}{ARTICLE\ \thesection:\ }{0pt}{}

\begin{document}

% . . .

\section{SCOPE OF CONTRACT}
\begin{easylist}
\ListProperties(Start1*=\thesection, Mark={.}, FinalMark=, Hang=true, Margin=0in, Align=0.5in, Space=6pt, Space*=6pt)

## The scope of the present Contract is to lay down the terms and conditions under which the SUPPLIER agrees to sell and deliver to the PURCHASER, and the PURCHASER agrees to purchase from the SUPPLIER the Equipment and Documentation at the terms and conditions as specified in this Contract and its Annexes.

## The material list, attached as Annex 1, is an integral part of this Contract and is in accordance with the Technical Terms and Conditions. Notarized Copies of the respective certificates of compliance of the Ministry for Telecommunication and Information of the Russian Federation (Minsvjazi) for the Equipment supplied under this Contract shall be handed over by the SUPPLIER to the PURCHASER immediately after signature of this Contract. 
\end{easylist}

% . . .

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use `\indent` before `\begin{easylist}` instead of using `\usepackage{indentfirst}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This seems to work.  You would improve your answer if you explained why it is effective.